# How to get a summary of all SharePoint discussion board posts that day

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I am using **SharePoint 2010** and have access to **SharePoint designer 2010** to create workflows. I would like to create a workflow that notifies users of all new discussion board posts made that day. This workflow would operate daily and provide the subject of all new discussion board posts.

Is there any way to implement this in a workflow?

Comment: Sounds more like a timer job kind of solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use timer jobs you can do this with pure SharePoint worfklow as well. You can use a custom list to gather all new discussion titles in the title field (an item a day) then wait for a specific time and send an e-mail containing all the titles.

What you need to achieve this:

1. An empty custom list called "New dicusssions"
2. A workflow to create/update an item in the "New discussions" list every time a discussion is added in the main discussions list.

   when creating a new item set the Title field to the discussion title

   when updating the item set the Title field to the current Title field value and i.e. a semicolon followed by the new discussion. Resulting in: Discussion 1; Discussion 2
3. A workflow that sends an e-mail at a specific time of day when an item is created in the "New discussions" list.
   When the email is sent it simply looks at the Title field to find the new discussions.

Challenges:

- Finding out if an item was already added to the "New discussions" list today, and if so updating it
- Getting the mail sending worfkflow to wait until a specific time of the current day (perhaps with the "Send time portion of a date/time field"?)